# How to use high charts in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, angular5, angular6

[image]

I am using High chart-stacked column bar chart. I can able to get the Bar with skyblue and white colors but I need a bar with points at 24, 41 and 49 y_axis points as shown in the picutre. Please help me in achieve this. Thanks in advance. The code which I tried so far.

```js
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Smaple';
  options = {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        tickInterval: 50,
        max: 100

    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
        },
        series: {
            borderColor: '#000'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Total',
        data: [{ y: 20, color: "white"}]
    }, {
        name: 'Actual',
        data: [{ y: 80, color: "skyblue"}],
    }]
};
```

Comment: Do you get the same error produced after clicking run the snippet when running locally? If not, please edit your post to include the errors.

Comment: No errors are displaying in the console. I cannot able to divide the bar blue color part during the intervals of 24,41 and 49 y_axis points as shown in the picture.

Comment: Could you prepare a simplified demo of your app/chart with sample data (for example codesandbox)? Highcharts does not provide such a type of column series, so probably it will be required to overwrite `drawGraph` method from column series prototype.

Comment: @WojciechChmiel https://codepen.io/User564/pen/WYYpLw my codepen link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Highcharts.SVGRenderer](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer) and render additional elements on each column. Firstly use [renderer.rect](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#rect) to create three rectangles, then [renderer.path](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path) to create the line beetwen them. Notice that each time the chart is rendered you have to destroy the old elements and render new ones. Check the demo I posted below.

HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

JS:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    events: {
      render: function() {
        var chart = this,
          series = chart.series[1],
          points = series.points,
          yAxis = chart.yAxis[0],
          customPoints = [
            24,
            41,
            49
          ],
          path = [],
          height = 7,
          element,
          width,
          x,
          y,
          i;

        if (chart.customElements) {
          chart.customElements.forEach(function(elem) {
            elem.destroy();
          });
        }

        chart.customElements = [];

        points.forEach(function(point) {
          if (point.series.visible) {
            x = point.plotX + chart.plotLeft;
            width = point.pointWidth * 0.2;

            for (i = 0; i < customPoints.length; i++) {
              y = yAxis.toPixels(customPoints[i]);

              if (i === 0) {
                path.push('M');
              } else {
                path.push('L');
              }

              path.push(x);
              path.push(y);

              element = chart.renderer.rect(x - (width / 2), y, width, height)
                .attr({
                  strokeWidth: 1,
                  fill: '#000'
                })
                .add()
                .toFront();

              chart.customElements.push(element);
            }

            element = chart.renderer.path(path)
              .attr({
                'stroke-width': 1,
                stroke: '#000',
                fill: '#000'
              })
              .add()
              .toFront();

            chart.customElements.push(element);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal',
    },
    series: {
      borderColor: '#000'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Total',
    data: [{
      y: 20,
      color: "white"
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Actual',
    data: [{
      y: 80,
      color: "skyblue"
    }]
  }]
});
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hn96dfwm/

Comment: That's perfect, thanks man. Here I need another small addition to the functionality. I want to add multiple bars with different y_axis values. Please help in getting this as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're welcome. Check this demo with multiple bars: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tbezu6kg/

Comment: How to add tooltip descriptions when I hover on different custom points that we added in code?

Comment: Default tooltip can't be used to show custom points description. You can use for example annotations to show point information when `mouseover` event on custom point (SVGElement) occurs. Check the demo I prepared you: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m8927ufx/.

Comment: I tried this code but I am getting an error "ERROR TypeError: chart.addAnnotation is not a function". I added annotation js file in my app.module.ts "import { AnnotationsModule } from 'highcharts/modules/annotations';" But It's not working

Comment: Try import it like that: `import * as AnnotationsModule from "highcharts/modules/annotations";` then initialize it: `AnnotationsModule(Highcharts);`. Check this demo with `highcharts-angular` wrapper that I encourage you to use: https://codesandbox.io/s/329llv6wj1.

Comment: Now I can able to load the annotations js file from app.module.ts but when I hover on the customPoints in the graph I am getting an error like "$ is not defined" in annotations.js file and when I remove hover, got another error "Type Error: chart.removeAnnotations is not a function".

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/znnv6prl3m I'm not sure whether it will reproduce the issue in codesandbox but I have added all my code and dependencies. Please check and let me know

Comment: You are using deprecated package `highcharts-annotations' as you can read on npm page. Annotations are a part of Highstock 6+ and Highcharts 6+ as a module. Fixed demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/5vnx7p8p8k.

Comment: I tried this as well but now I'm getting the error **chart.addAnnotation is not a function** and **chart.removeAnnotation is not a function** and even I cannot see any methods like _addAnnotation_ or _removeAnnotation_ in highcharts/modules/annotations.js file

Comment: Could you reproduce it somehow? As you can see on the example posted above it works fine. Perhaps you use the old version of highcharts there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185040/discussion-between-user-and-wojciech-chmiel).

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

Install library

```
npm install --save highcharts
```

In your component where you desire render the chart:

```
    import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

    // Imports all modules you need and then inicialized
    declare var require: any;
    let Boost = require('highcharts/modules/boost');
    let Pareto = require('highcharts/modules/pareto');
    let noData = require('highcharts/modules/no-data-to-display');
    let More = require('highcharts/highcharts-more');
    
    Boost(Highcharts);
    noData(Highcharts);
    Pareto(Highcharts);
    More(Highcharts);
    noData(Highcharts);


   export class YourNameComponent implements OnInit {

    options: any = {
    title: {
      text: null // Your title
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'spline'  // type chart
    },
    tooltip: {
      crosshairs: true,
      shared: true
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Ventas'
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Mobiliario'
      },
      categories: [] // Your categories
    },
    legend: {
      layout: 'vertical',
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },
    plotOptions: {
      spline: {
        marker: {
          radius: 4,
          lineColor: '#666666',
          lineWidth: 1
        }
      }
    },
    series: [] // Your data series
  };

    ngOnInit(): void {
     this.initChart();
    }


    initChart(): void {
       const idElementHtml = 'your id chart container';
       const chartR = document.getElementById(idElementHtml) // or you can use ViewChild as well;
       if (typeof chartR !== undefined && chartR !== null){
          Highcharts.chart(idElementHtml, this.options);
       }
    }
  }
}
```